# Taskbar Minimize C# Windows Form Problem

Tags: c#, winforms, taskbar, minimize

I have a Windows Form application that, when the form is Activated, Deactivated, or SizeChanged, the form does something.  It's rather specific.  For example:

**Form Activated**:  Will set the variable `isActive` to true, and focus the input to an input box for someone to enter something too.

**Form Deactivated**:  Will set the variable `isActive` to false, so that any focus changes in the application (caused by remote machine messages, chat messages, etc), does not steal focus from other applications.

Right now, I have my `webBrowser1.Focus()` command inside of the `Form Activated` event which isn't ideal, as when you click on the taskbar icon, it tries to minimize, but since it focuses back to the web browser, the form is then restored/activated again.

I did some searching here on Stack Overflow, and found the following information:

**Edited for the below information:**

I did find this information in another post here on Stack Overflow:

```
protected void OnActivateApp(bool activate)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Activate {0}", activate);
}

protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
{
    // Trap WM_ACTIVATEAPP
    if (m.Msg == 0x1c) OnActivateApp(m.WParam != IntPtr.Zero);
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

But the behavior is similar to the problem I'm seeing with the above 2 events.  When the taskbar icon is CLICKED, the form does catch the Deactivated:

> Activate False

But then immediately, it does this:

> Activate True

It would appear, that when you minimize a window with the taskbar button, it still remains as the 'focused' application until you click on another application.

One of the posts did suggest I capture the `GotFocus` of the form, but there is no event that I can find for a form level for `GotFocus`, as `GotFocus` is derived from a control, not an application form.

**Question:**  How do I allow the form to be minimized with the taskbar button, and when the form is then reshown, get it to do the `webBrowser1.Focus()` command to put the focus where it should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I had thought the GotFocus Event would work against the Form but it seems not to fire when the focus on the window itself changes.

So I took the liberty of writing code that does work. It taps into the Form Resize Event instead. I left event handlers for your Activated and Deactivate events in case they were still required but I dont think they should be. Just be sure to call 'Refresh' so the form repaints and the focus moves.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private bool isActive = false;
    private FormWindowState previousstate;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        previousstate = this.WindowState;
        //Got Focus Anonymous Delegate handles focus on the textbox
        //if the Form currently is Activated
        this.Resize += delegate(object resizesender, EventArgs resizee)
        {
            //if (previousstate == FormWindowState.Minimized)
            // {
                txtGetFocus.Focus();
                this.Refresh();
            // }
            previousstate = this.WindowState;
        };
        this.Activated += delegate(object activatedsender, EventArgs activatede)
        {
            isActive = true;
        };
        this.Deactivate += delegate(object deactivatesender, EventArgs deactivatee)
        {
            isActive = false;
        };
    }
}
```

I commented out a test case in the event you want to suppress movement based on a certain Windowstate. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I ended up solving the problem. Previously, I was calling Focus() on the ActiveElement in OnActivated. However, in addition to the taskbar minimization call you noticed, pressing Alt-tab to give your form focus **also** doesn't cause a call to OnActivated.

As a result, I chose to look at the WM_ACTIVATE message to determine when to give focus. From the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646274(v=vs.85).aspx):

> wParam
>
> The low-order word specifies whether the window is being activated or
>   deactivated. This parameter can be one of the following values. The
>   high-order word specifies the minimized state of the window being
>   activated or deactivated. A nonzero value indicates the window is
>   minimized.

```
[SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]
protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
{
    base.WndProc(ref message);
    if (message.Msg == 0x6)
    {
        int highOrderWord = (int)((message.WParam.ToInt32() & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16);
        bool minimized = highOrderWord != 0;
        bool activating = message.WParam != IntPtr.Zero;
        if (activating && !minimized)
        {
            this.FocusBrowserElement();
        }
    }
}


private void FocusBrowserElement()
{
    if (!this.webBrowser.IsDisposed && 
         this.webBrowser.Document != null &&
         this.webBrowser.Document.ActiveElement != null)
    {
        this.webBrowser.Document.ActiveElement.Focus();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like your approach with the focuses and this is a brutal hack but you could postpone the change of focus for one second liek this:

```
Thread t = new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate(){
  Thread.Sleep(1000);
  this.Invoke(methodChangingFocus, new object[] {});
}).Start();
```

That could give the opportunity to the user to press the minimize button.

Comment: I didn't like my approach either; that's why i asked here.  I do apologize if it was offensive, was never my intention :(

Comment: `Thread.Sleep()` has absolutely no place here at all. Shame on you!